# How does the +3 for class skills work when multiclassing a new class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Inspired by this question:
[Class skill +3, when you have 1 rank in that skill](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16211/class-skill-3-when-you-have-1-rank-in-that-skill)

OK, I have a fighter with a ranks in (for example) Acrobatics.  Then I gain a level and add a Rogue.  Now, if I started as a Rogue, or add ranks after the fighter multi-classes, I know he will get the +3 bonus, but if you have the ranks in the skill BEFORE multi-classing and then the skill becomes a class skill do you get the bonus or have to wait until you put more rank(s) into that skill?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For [Skills](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/usingSkills.html) when you multiclass all your skills immediately get the +3 class bonus provided you have at least one one rank in them.

Thus for your example:

Bob the fighter has 1 rank in acrobatics, and no stat bonus.

Bob gets +1 bonus.

Bob levels and takes 1 level in rogue. Bob now get +3 to acrobatics as acrobatics is a class skill for rogues, even though he bought this rank in acrobatics when he was a fighter. Where the rank came from is irrelevant, now Bob is a rogue it's a class skill for him.

Bob now has +4 bonus.

Comment: I was thinking this is the way, but could not find anything specifically detailed in either the Core Rulebook, or the http://www.d20pfsrd.com/

Comment: It doesn't address it specifically because it works like the skill rules say without modification.  Yes, when you multiclass and get new class skills, they become class skills and work like class skills, and you can get the +3 in them if you have a rank.